# Use Record typescript utility types

Tags: typescript

I have the next situation:

```
interface ThreeStringProps {
    vars?:  'prop1' | 'prop3'
 }
const obj: Record<ThreeStringProps['vars'], string> = {
    prop1: 'adsx', prop3: 'sd'
}
```

Doing that i got:

```
Type 'string | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
```

I tried to solve this using `Required`

````
    vars?:  'prop1' | 'prop3'
 }
const obj: Record<Required<ThreeStringProps['vars']>, string> = {
    prop1: 'adsx', prop3: 'sd'
}```
but without success, because i got the same errors. <br> How to fix my code? <br> vars should be optional in my interface.
````

Comment: `Required<ThreeStringProps>["vars"]` or `NonNullable<ThreeStringProps["vars"]>` or `ThreeStringProps["vars"] & string` or `Exclude<ThreeStringProps["vars"], undefined>`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to make `prop1` and `prop3` mandatory:

```
interface ThreeStringProps {
  vars?:  'prop1' | 'prop3';
}

const obj: Record<NonNullable<ThreeStringProps['vars']>, string> = {
  prop1: "...",
  prop3: "..."
};
```

As mentioned by @caTS: [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) also works (I did it wrong in the first place, my bad).

Comment: `Required` does work - you just have to use it on `ThreeStringProps` first before accessing `"vars"`.

Comment: @caTS Oh, my bad. You are totally right.

Comment: @caTS, what do you mean?

Comment: @Asking My comment includes 4 ways of solving the problem. The first of which is proper use of `Required`.